# Python pip/conda install PyMC3 error

Tags: python, pip, installation, conda, pymc3

I am running on Windows 10 and have Python 2.7, Python 3.5, and Anaconda. I want to install PyMC3 and run it in Python 3 in a jupyter notebook. However no matter what method of installation I try, I cannot seem to get it to run.

I have tried all of the following routes for installing PyMC3 (using both pip and pip3),

```
conda install mingw libpython
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
pip install git+https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3

git clone https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3
cd pymc3
pip install -r requirements.txt

pip install pymc3

conda install -c conda-forge pymc3

conda install -c conda-forge pymc3=3.0
```

Originally I was getting the following error,

```
'Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\<name>
\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-405gszhk\scipy\
```

Along with the error

```
microsoft visual c++ 14.0 is required. get it with "microsoft visual c++ build tools": 
http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

So in installed visual studio build tools, and additionally reinstalled pretty much everything else from Python to Anaconda to pip etc. Now when I try and install I run into more issues regarding scipy (I already have this package installed), and now get the following error,

```
Command "c:\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\<name>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-
_jieb6ca\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code,
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp\
pip-98gozauj-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed 
--compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp\
pip-build-_jieb6ca\scipy\
```

even if some of the above commands for installation do not throw an error, I still run into this,

```
import pymc3 as pm
---------------------------------------------------------
ImportError             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1a95cb4612db> in <module>()
----> 1 import pymc3 as pm

ImportError: No module named 'pymc3'
```

Any suggestions on what is failing and how I can install PyMC3 would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to install pymc3 with pip at all? That's the whole point of conda, to package built libraries so that you don't have to build them from source with pip.

Comment: I started trying whatever I could once conda wouldn't work.

Comment: Why didn't conda work? What error messages did you get from conda before you started using pip?

Answer (score 4):

**Installation of pymc3 with python 3.6 for windows 10**

I've had serious problems to find an installation that makes pymc3 work properly. With "import pymc3" I've got a fatal error usually. According to the many blog contributions - which I tested all.... - it does seem to be a procedure not completely stable yet. BUT: based on the Anaconda distribution the follwing did work for me (**for Jupyter also**):

(see also: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html)

1. conda install theano
2. conda install pygpu
3. pip install pymc3 (*pip necessary when using python 3.6*)

Comment: It worked for me with conda instead of pip in the third command with Python 3.8.10

Answer (score 2):

This works too.

```
from pip._internal import main
     try:
     import pymc3
except:
     from pip._internal import main
     main(['install', 'pymc3'])
     import pymc3
```